# Creating subgroups from categorical data by using lapply in R

Tags: r, variables, using, lapply

I was wondering if you kind folks could answer a question I have. In the sample data I've provided below, in column 1 I have a categorical variable, and in column 2 p-values.

```
x <- c(rep("A",0.1*10000),rep("B",0.2*10000),rep("C",0.65*10000),rep("D",0.05*10000))
categorical_data=as.matrix(sample(x,10000))
p_val=as.matrix(runif(10000,0,1))
combi=as.data.frame(cbind(categorical_data,p_val))
head(combi)

  V1                V2
1  A 0.484525170875713
2  C  0.48046557046473
3  C 0.228440979029983
4  B 0.216991128632799
5  C 0.521497668232769
6  D 0.358560319757089
```

I want to now take one of the categorical variables, let's say "C", and create another variable if it is C (print 1 in column 3, or 0 if it isn't).

```
combi$NEWVAR[combi$V1=="C"] <-1
combi$NEWVAR[combi$V1!="C" <-0

  V1                V2 NEWVAR
1  A 0.484525170875713 0
2  C  0.48046557046473 1
3  C 0.228440979029983 1
4  B 0.216991128632799 0
5  C 0.521497668232769 1
6  D 0.358560319757089 0
```

I'd like to do this for each of the variables in V1, and then loop over using lapply:

```
variables=unique(combi$V1)

loopeddata=lapply(variables,function(x){
combi$NEWVAR[combi$V1==x] <-1
combi$NEWVAR[combi$V1!=x]<-0
}
)
```

My output however looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1] 0

[[4]]
[1] 0
```

My desired output would be like the table in the second block of code, but when looping over the third column would be A=1, while B,C,D=0. Then B=1, A,C,D=0 etc.

If anyone could help me out that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I am sure someone can help you with your immediate problem, but do you mind to elaborate on what you wish to achieve in the end with the new variable? Perhaps there are alternative ways to reach your desired goal. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, thanks Henrik. I'd want to do a mann-whitney U rank test on the different output tables, using the wilcox.test(V2~combi$NEWVAR). Essentially, I'd want to compare the rank of A against B,C,D combined, then B against A,C,D combined etc. That was the purpose of the third column. Note I'm aware this is just simulated data in my example, but my actual data has exactly the same format. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
model.matrix(~ -1 + V1, data=combi)
```

Then you can `cbind` it to `combi` if you desire:

```
combi <- cbind(combi, model.matrix(~ -1 + V1, data=combi))
```

Comment: That's some weird R witchcraft going on there. Exactly what I wanted, and bonus points for not using lapply or creating more than a single table. I'll take a closer look at the model.matrix function. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`model.matrix` is definitely the way to do this in R. You can, however, also consider using `table`.

Here's an example using the result I get when using `set.seed(1)` (always use a seed when sharing example problems with random data).

```
LoopedData <- table(sequence(nrow(combi)), combi$V1)
head(LoopedData)
#    
#     A B C D
#   1 0 1 0 0
#   2 0 0 1 0
#   3 0 0 1 0
#   4 0 0 1 0
#   5 0 1 0 0
#   6 0 0 1 0

## If you want to bind it back with the original data
combi <- cbind(combi, as.data.frame.matrix(LoopedData))

head(combi)
#   V1                 V2 A B C D
# 1  B 0.0647124934475869 0 1 0 0
# 2  C  0.676612401846796 0 0 1 0
# 3  C  0.735371692571789 0 0 1 0
# 4  C  0.111299667274579 0 0 1 0
# 5  B 0.0466546178795397 0 1 0 0
# 6  C  0.130910312291235 0 0 1 0
```